# MongoDB with Mongoid in Rails - Geospatial Indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, geolocation, mongoid

MongoDB has a very nice [Geospatial Indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) feature. How can I use it in Rails with Mongoid?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can define geo indexes like this in mongoid

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :loc, :type => Array

  index(
      [
          [:loc, Mongo::GEO2D]             
      ], background: true

  )
end
```

And for queries

**$near** command (without maxDistance)

```
 location = [80.24958300000003, 13.060422]
 items = Item.where(:loc => {"$near" => location})
```

**$near** command (with maxDistance)

```
 distance = 10 #km
 location = [80.24958300000003, 13.060422]
 items = Item.where(:loc => {"$near" => location , '$maxDistance' => distance.fdiv(111.12)})
```

Convert distance by 111.12 (one degree is approximately 111.12 kilometers) when using km, or leave distance as it is on using degree

**$centerSphere / $nearSphere**  queries

```
location = [80.24958300000003, 13.060422]
items = Item.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$centerSphere" => [location, (distance.fdiv(6371) )]}})
```

This will find the items within the 10 km radius. Here we need to convert the distance/6371(earth radius) to get it work with km.

**$box** (bounding box queries)

```
 first_loc = [80.24958300000003, 13.060422]
 second_loc = [81.24958300000003, 12.060422]
 items = Item.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$box" => [first_loc, second_loc]}})
```

This will help you to find the items within the given bounding box.

Comment: When I try using $near command (with maxDistance) it returns an error: 

geo values have to be numbers: { $maxDistance: 0.001799856011519079, $near: [ 80.249, 13.060422 ] }

Any thoughts? It works with just "$near" in place, but when I add "$maxDistance", it chokes.

Comment: @Vasily, i am not sure.. the $near query with $maxdistance works perfectly fine with the values you specified. `Item.where(:loc => {"$near" =>  [ 80.249, 13.060422 ] , '$maxDistance' =>  0.001799856011519079})`. it works fine.. May be you can show me the query you were trying? we ll see then

Comment: I've got same error when I use maxDistance. Ruby 1.8. Did you guys find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

RameshVel's answer is great.

As an update, in Mongoid 3.0.4, I had to define the index as follows to make it work with `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`:

```
index(
  { loc: Mongo::GEO2D },
  { background: true }
)
```

Comment: Actually this didn't work for me with `Mongoid 3.0.0`, the documentation indicates the following format `index({ loc: "2d" }, { min: -200, max: 200 })`. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

All those answers are a outdated with newest versions of MongoDB and will throw some `uninitialized constant Mongo::GEO2D`

For mongoid 4/5, I suggest you have  look at the [mongoid-geospatial gem](https://github.com/nofxx/mongoid-geospatial) if you need to play with 2D Objects or coordinates.