# Units to use for maxdistance and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to get my head around MongoDB and geospatial searches.
Basically what I want is for users to be able to query documents (images) that
are shot within a set distance from the users current location. So I the user is searching for all images that are shot within 1 km from where he is standing I try to use 
the below example but I have no idea what to set as the maxdistance value.

```
db.places.find({ loc : { $near : [50,50] , $maxDistance : 5 }})
```

So my question is what do I set as maxdistance if I am searching for documents
within a 1 km radius?

I am totally stuck here.

Answer (score 70):

In order to use mongodb `$near` queries with km bounds, you need to convert the radius value to km. By default mongodb $near accepts `$maxDistance` as `radius`.

Convert distance by `111.12` (one degree is approximately 111.12 kilometers) when using km, or leave distance as it is on using degree

to your question

> what do I set as maxdistance if I am searching for documents within a
>   1 km radius?

you can use this

```
   db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] , $maxDistance : 1/111.12 } } )
```

I have answered how to use [mongo geospatial features here in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702244/mongodb-with-mongoid-in-rails-geospatial-indexing/7702456#7702456). You can check out

Comment: Cool, thanks! What is the difference between $near and $nearSphere?

Comment: $near assumes an idealized model of a flat earth, meaning that an arcdegree of latitude (y) and longitude (x) represent the same distance everywhere. So you have to convert the radius by 111 or 69 to get the results.But $nearSphere  you need to convert the radius by  (6371 km or 3959 miles) to get it work...  you can read more about [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-TheEarthisRoundbutMapsareFlat)

Comment: Is it possible to query a fraction?

Comment: Here the units are mentioned in the docs. Took a while to find this...  
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/maxDistance/  
  
Thanks for the conversion, @RameshVel! More accurate conversion here:  
http://www.chemical-ecology.net/java/lat-long.htm  
shows 111.11999965975954 km / degree (I'm working at the meter scale, so accuracy is important).

Comment: I should add that value varies for longitude degrees as you move away from the equator. Makes sense...

Comment: Here's a question where this approach doesn't seem to work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19496883/1331671

Answer (score 16):

Since version **2.4** of MongoDB you can specify the radius directly in meters as a value of **$maxDistance**, like this:

```
db.<collection>.find({loc: {$near : 
                               {$geometry : 
                                   {
                                    type: 'Point', 
                                    coordinates: [<longitude> , <latitude>]       
                                   }
                               }, 
                               $maxDistance: 10*100 
                           }
                     });
```

Comment: It depends on the index. If the index is `2d` this won't work, because a 2d-index assumes «radian format». If the index on the other hand is `2dsphere` you are correct. :-)
Documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#query-on-legacy-coordinates

Comment: Here, Max distance is in meter or kilometer?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions I am using Spring and Mongo 4.0.5. Important thing is type of index and location data type. I am using 2dsphere,org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.geo.GeoJsonPoint
Later on it generate corresponding mongo query with geometry with distance in meters.

```
{ "location" : { "$nearSphere" : { "$geometry" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [18.341772, 43.834183] }, "$maxDistance" : 331.0 }
```