# mongodb's find over nodejs 2d index with $near returns as an empty find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

I'm trying to get some results from my places collection which are close to a coordinate. For this purpose, I'm using a 2d index over a location.position attribute which has a lng and lat attribute.

The problem is that every coordinate I put, it returns the same 60 results (the whole collection).

The docs in my collection are all from near to my GPS coordinate and, however, if I put a 0.0, 0.0 coordinate or any other pair, it returns always the same.

In fact, the query returns exactly the same if I use an empty find().

The index seems to be created correctly as it is not returning any error.

An object in my collection is like this:

```
{ "_id" : "80293840923...", 
"name": "myname", 
"location" : { 
"position" : { "lng": -196988, "lat": 43.30594 } 
"address": "example", 
"city": "example"  } 
}
```

The index is created like this:

```
places_collection.ensureIndex({"location.position": "2d"}, {name: "index2dLocation"}, function(error, indexName){
    callback("", "Indice creado: " + indexName)
});
```

The search would be like this:

```
places_collection.find( 
{ "location.position" : { $near : [ parseFloat(-123.98) , parseFloat(162.342) ] } }
).toArray(function(error, results) {
          if( error ){ callback(error, "")
          }else{ console.log(results.length); callback(null, results); }
});
```

And finally, as said before, my search returns always the same result. It doesn't care if I put one coordinate or another. Even it doesn't care if I make a empty find().

Any help here please? I don't know how to make it work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the solution was to add the `$maxDistance` property to avoid all the docs which are more far than the radius in the `$maxDistance`.

If you don't put that property and you only have 10 docs located near to one coordinate, if you make a find in a very far coordinate, it will still return the same 10 docs because you don't have more docs near to the new coordinate.

In addition, it's important to say that `$maxDistance`'s unit is in **degrees**, so here was my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841830/974828

To convert degrees to kilometers, you have to divide by 111.12.

So here is the result:

```
 db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] , $maxDistance : 1/111.12 } } )
```