# Mongo GeoLocation query results in error

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongodb-query

I have been using below query for a while & it was working as expected. Today I removed all the documents in `users` collection from terminal & getting `Mongo Error`.

Query:

```
neighbors query: {
  "geoInfo.location": {
    "$near": {
      "$maxDistance": 160000,
      "$geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          101.69558548629793,
          3.046124475906546
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "gender": "female",
  "_id": {
    "$nin": [
      "6f6ca0ecdfc96c74cc90624ce8e915cb"
    ]
  }
}
```

Errors:

```
[MongoError: point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: 160000.0, 1: 0.0 }] name: 'MongoError'
```

Above query gives -

```
error: {
    "$err" : "point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: 160000.0, 1: 0.0 }",
    "code" : 16433
}
```

on mongo console.

Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Based on the error message, it seems like you might have a `geoInfo.location` point in your database with a longitude of 160000? You mention removing all documents in the `users` collection, but the query appears to be against `neighbors`; is it actually the `neighbors` collection that should be empty?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the distance you provided until now in metres is now perceived in radians.

[$near](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) documentation is not great. Care to take a look at the [indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#index-feature-geospatial) of that collection?

[Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837731/units-to-use-for-maxdistance-and-mongodb?rq=1) use the easy fix of dividing distance in km by 111.12 (one degree is approximately 111.12 kilometers)